# php+curl to send a post request with fields

Tags: php, api, curl

trying to send **post** request to api, to get an image back.

example url:

```
https://providers.cloudsoftphone.com/lib/prettyqr/createQR.php?user=1003123&format=png&cloudid=asdasdasd&pass=123123123
```

the above url works fine in the browser,
the api doesnt care if the request is get/post,

result of my code is always **'invalid input'**.

code:

```
$url='https://providers.cloudsoftphone.com/lib/prettyqr/createQR.php';
$u = rand();
$p = rand();

$fields = array(
    'user'=> urlencode($u),
    'pass'=> urlencode($p),
    'format'=> urlencode('jpg'), 
    'cloudid' => urlencode('test')
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

on a side note: is there a way to debug the request in order to see what is being sent ?

Comment: The URL you provided is in `GET` request format, so if you are directly pasting that URL in browser then it will make GET request only. But in your code you have used `POST` it seems.

Comment: yes, I've mentioned it to make it clear that the API does return an image on a post request. tested with hurl.it

Comment: Ok, But I tried using `Advance Rest Client` it isn't working with `POST` request. Only for `GET` request its working.

Comment: @Log1c Please check again since it's working OK for me ?

Comment: Not working dude. FYI while testing for POST you should't pass parameters in URL. here is my test result http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/5358fe38d31971-20758372

Comment: @Log1c I hope you're right because that will mean Im not insane. Thanks

Comment: Just use GET method instead after-all its working. :)

Comment: from what I know GET is unsecure, or atleast not as POST. since Im sending user and pass in the request.. maybe you believe otherwise?

Comment: Yup, GET isn't secure. but in your case while requesting from `curl` user won't get notified about such URL parameters. Because request will be sending from your web server and not from client/user's browser. You'l just output the response image you got from URL.

Comment: Please add an answer with the above info and Ill accept it. You've been helpful thanks

Comment: Sure, give me a moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL provided isn't working for `POST` request. Here is resulting screenshot (I tried using [Advance Rest Client](http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/5358fe38d31971-20758372))

[image]

However Its working perfectly with `GET` method. So you can continue using GET request method to generate QR code.

I agree that GET isn't much secure compare to POST method but in your case while requesting from curl user won't get to know about such URL parameters (userid, password). *Because `curl` request will be sending from your web server and not from client/user's browser.*

Later you can just output the response image you got from the api.